# Replace div html with this attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code

```
<div content="Something 1">Content 1</div>
<div content="Something 2">Content 2</div>
<div content="Something 3">Content 3</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to replace content of HTML with this `content` attribute.

```
<div content="Something 1">Something 1</div>
<div content="Something 2">Something 2</div>
<div content="Something 3">Something 3</div>
```

I don't know how to select multi object.
Any one help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to select them. All DIVs whose ID starts with "Something"? Can you give them a class?

Comment: Are you sure your question is well written? It's hard to understand what you actually want. And BTW `ID` should NOT contain spaces.

Comment: Since whitespace isn't allowed in ID, you might want to consider changing them.

Comment: Id is only my example, i use another attribute for this.

Comment: Edit my question with other attribute. But problem is solved, thanks to Charlie for nice answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `ID`'s cannot contain spaces.

This will replace all instances of `Content x` with `Something x`, getting `x` from the `id`.

```
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/xuGEq/2/**

This will replace all instances of `Content x` with `Something 1`:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).text("Something 1");
});
```

**Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/xuGEq/1/**

Comment: Somebody please explain to my why this is downvoted twice. Also, don't forget to mark this is as your answer if it does indeed solve your problem.

Comment: Charlie, I would start my answer that it's wrong to have `id` containing spaces, there more I'd suggest to use the *starts with* selector `id^=Something`.

Comment: While this does answer the question, you didn't mention that `id` cannot contain spaces. (I didn't downvote you btw.)

Comment: @roXon I can't disagree with your first point. The OP, however, never stated that he only wanted to select certain `div` elements. Sure, I could've probably figured that out, but downvoting over something that was never stated in the first place seems silly to me.

Comment: Even I finished up with my fiddle a minute ago :) http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/tQu35/ You have solved the query otherwise.

Comment: No need to use `each` - just pass `text` a function - http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text (not downvoting, just saying)

Comment: Don't get down due to downvotes, believe me that people who downvote usually come back to the answers to see if there was some improvements. I know it's not likable to see an answer be downvoted, specially if the downvoter doesn't leave a valid comment- suggestion, but it's something we (brave programmers) have to deal with. Be voted, and downvoted without hard feelings. Hope one day you'll have to leave a comment in order to downvote the questions/answer, but that will probably lead to other issues, I think there's more on *meta*. Any way +1 from me. Happy coding!

Comment: @lan: `text` cannot get attribute to replace, `each` is good in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your id's will start with the prefix something, use:

```
$("div[id^='Something']").text("Something 1")
```

If what you are looking for is to edit all the div tags in your document, you could simply:

```
$("div").text("Something 1")
```

If you know exactly what html tags are those that you want to edit, I recommend you to mark them with a class. Lets say:

```
<div id="Something 1" class="editable">Content 1</div>
<div id="Something 2" class="editable">Content 2</div>
<div id="Something 3" class="editable">Content 3</div>
```

This way you could simply do:

```
$(".editable").text("Something 1")
```

In case you want to modify their inner text. or:

```
$(".editable").html("<strong>Something 1</strong>")
```

In case you want to give them a richer format modifying not only their text but also their inner HTML.

It is a bad practice to use ids with spaces. Chrome won't complain about it, but
some other browser will. So only in case you are using ids like "Something 1", it would be better to use "something_1" (It is a convention to use lowercase for attributes and html tags).

Here you have a link that explain how selectors work in jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I suspect you missed this suggestion: `Something_1` and please for the sake of our community don't post links to `w3schools`. http://w3fools.com/ And this guys wrote this article right in time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the dark story of w3schools. And you were right, I missed that suggestion.

For the sake of our community, downvote the question. It is obvious that this person didn't looked for an answer before asking.

Comment: I have to agree with you, but for some people that are not English speakers could be quite difficult to always find the right terms while "googleing". We have to be patient and give our best. In any case the SO *comm.* will decide if to close/remove the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you dont want to affect all the divs on the page, but only the one containing something in their id...

```
$("[id^=Something]").each(function(){
    $(this).text("Something 1");
});
```

Note that using spaces inside a id is not the way to go,  you should name them somthing like "something1" ....